# Is it required to restart JVM after adding certificates in Keystore?

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-ee, openssl, keystore

After adding certificates in java keystore file i am getting following exception

Error opening socket: java.net.SocketException:
 java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException:
 Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext) EXCEPTION:[SOAPException:

I doubt if it is required to restart JVM after adding certificates. I couldn't start JVM as certificates are added on production server and it will be restarted on release window only which is 15 days after today date.

Comment: Well i noticed that when JVM is restarted it reloads the keystore , if keystore is corrupted it will throw error while loading keystore on jvm restart otherwise keystore will list all the certificate information in the logs.